# Is it possible to lock a single Google Slides presentation slide?

Tags: google-slides

Google Sheets has this great feature to protect ranges.

Does Google Slides have a similar feature to protect (lock) a single slide to prevent others from editing it?

Comment: All that does is to skip the slide in a presentation. I am working in a group on a shared Google slide project and need to know how can I lock and protect ONLY MY SLIDES so that other members of my group cannot make changes.

Comment: I have the same question, difficult to make a template for everyone to use when they all modify the first slide...

Answer (score -3):

yes.right click . press skip slide.

Comment: Can you elaborate more as to how this answers the question.  This doesn't sound like a means to lock the slide.

Comment: this won't work because as noted in [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1694830) `if you share your presentation with others, people will be able to see the skipped slides`